# How to calculate the Intersection over Union (IoU) of any two bounding boxes in 3D space?

Tags: python, graphics, 3d, geometry

Given two Oblique Bounding Boxes (OBBs) in 3D space, how can we calculate their Intersection over Union (IoU)?
[image]

I have attempted to solve this problem using the following method, but the results are incorrect (although this method may work for Axis-Aligned Bounding Boxes (AABBs)):

```
def naive_iou(box1,box2):
'''
3D IoU calculate
The box representation format is [x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2], which represents the coordinates of two diagonal points.
'''
 in_w = min(box1[3],box2[3]) - max(box1[0],box2[0])
 in_l = min(box1[4],box2[4]) - max(box1[1],box2[1])
 in_h = min(box1[5],box2[5]) - max(box1[2],box2[2])

 inter = 0 if in_w < 0 or in_l < 0 or in_h < 0 else in_w * in_l * in_h
 union = (box1[3] - box1[0]) * (box1[4] - box1[1]) * (box1[5] - box1[2]) + (box2[3] - box2[0]) * (box2[4] - box2[1]) * (box2[5] - box2[2])  - inter
 iou = inter / union
```

Comment: there's probably a bunch of smart algorithms for this. perhaps this involves intersecting a bunch of planes. the result will be a complex solid. it might even have a hole or cavity.